# AngularJS, Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Nav Bar - Hover for Sub Menus

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rvP7pLi82xeKr8RMLm6c?p=preview):**

**This is the snippet in question.**

```
<ul class="nav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu': item.submenu && item.submenu.length}">
      <a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.name}}</a>
   <ul ng-if="item.submenu && item.submenu.length" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.submenu"><a href="{{subitem.link}}">{{subitem.name}}</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I have spent hours trying to find any example of a responsive navigation bar written with AngularJS, utilizing Twitter bootstrap, where the sub menu appears, not by click, but by hovering over the parent menu item.

**You would think someone had done this already?!?!**

My menu items 1, 2 & 3 are using Angular for data and the mouseover is working, however the position is wrong.

I realize it is a ".dropdown-menu" & ".dropdown-menu>dropdown-submenu" styling that is causing the positioning problem.

I am pretty sure the correct class association is ".dropdown" & ".dropdown>dropdown-menu" but I have played with all variations and it will cause the dropdown menus not to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you expect the position to be?

Comment: like the drop down parent item